# Is there a website fix for images not displaying after ios update to 15.4.1

Tags: ios, wordpress, image

A recent update to ios 15.4.1 has resulted in some images not displaying on my (Wordpress) website, for users only on affected ios devices. A 'fix' for this issue is possible:

by changing Settings>Safari>Advanced>Experimental Features

( Source:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/iphone-update/ )

Toggle the following Safari Experimental Features to ON (all others OFF):

- Aspect Ratio of < img >
- CSS Aspect Ratio
- CSS Color 4 Color Types
- GPU Process: Canvas Rendering
- GPU Process: Media
- GPU Process: Video Capture
- ImageBitmap
- Intersection Observer
- Media Session API
- NSURL Session WebSocket
- Private Click Measurement Fr
- VP9 decoder
- Web Share API Level 2
- WebGL 2.0
- WebGL via Metal
- WebM MSE parser
- WebM Web Audio
- WebRTC Platform Codecs
- WebRTC Platform TCP Sockets
- WebRTC Platform UDP Sockets
- WebRTC VP9 profile 0 codec

THIS FIXED THE ISSUE WITH THE WEBSITE IMAGES NOT DISPLAYING.
However, getting users to do this is NOT AN OPTION.

How can I ensure images display on my website on ios without having to change these safari settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by going to Elementor > Settings > Experiments and turning off and on "Improved asset loading".